How does Windows 11 determine which taskbar items are related and should be grouped?
If you open 3 instances of Notepad, you get 3 items on the taskbar which are all grouped together.  If you try to click and drag one of them, they all move.  If you then open a Chrome window, you can obviously move the taskbar item for that around without all of the Notepad taskbar items being moved.  How does Windows 11 determine which taskbar items are related and need to stay joined together?
There are lots of questions about how to prevent Windows 11 from grouping items from the same app in the taskbar.  I had previously used Taskbar Tweaker in Windows 10 which worked perfectly and allowed me to move each item on the taskbar independently.  While getting back to that state is my ultimate goal, I hoped to better understand how the grouping works.
I naively tried simply copying an application's exe and renaming it in a different directory, but that behaved the same as though both windows were opened using the same application.  Is it using some hash of the exe?
